# How to check whether i have iphone sdk installed or not on mac

Tags: mac, iphone

I am using MAC inside vmware.

I can see iphone simulator , Xcode 3.1.4 installed.

i want to see that whether i have iphone sdk installed or not. how can i check that

Answer (score 1):

Look under /Developer/SDKs

Note that Xcode 3.1.4 is quite old - you might be better off just downloading and install the latest Xcode and iPhone SDK.

Comment: the problem is i have only 3 gb space left on mac ,

Comment: You need to get more disk space then - you're going to run into problems soon enough whether you update to the latest Xcode and iPhone SDK or not.

Comment: Actually am using vmware image of MAC ans its Hraddisk is 16GB only.
I can't re-size its Disk space .don't know what to do

Comment: It's not rocket science to re-size a virtual disk. However it is apparent that what you are doing is illegal - running OS X on non-Apple hardware is contrary to the OS X license. If you're serious about doing iPhone development then you should just go the legal route and spend some money a cheap Mac (e.g. Mac Mini) - you can always sell it later on eBay.